# Do Azure virtual networks allow public addressing to sources in the VPN domain after connecting to the peer or Azure virtual network gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We have a client that does not support NAT or RFC1918 addressing within VPN tunnels (encryption domain) and/or Peers.

The Azure virtual network gateways setup without a load balancer appear to not do NAT unless you have a load balancer out front which is good, correct me if I am wrong.

But can internal virtual machines in the virtual network at Azure have public ips only? Or does Azure require private virtual network addressing but you can also associate the public IP?  We have set it up with the gateway public ip, virtual network with a 10.x.x.x subnet and associated public IPs to the sources or virtual machines.

Can virtual network machines only have a public IP at Azure? Or can you reach instances by public IP when connected to the Azure virtual network public IP even with private addressing in addition to the public IP binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can internal virtual machines in the virtual network at Azure have
>   public ips only? Or does Azure require private virtual network
>   addressing but you can also associate the public IP?

Every Azure VM create by a private IP address, then we can associate a public IP address to it.

> Or can you reach instances by public IP when connected to the Azure
>   virtual network public IP even with private addressing in addition to
>   the public IP binding?

Yes, we can connect that VM with public IP address directly.